# Server.TransferRequest is not preserving HttpContext.Items

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, url-rewriting

I've just updated my ASP.Net code from HttpContext.RewritePath(targetPath) to use the .Net 3.5 function: HttpContext.Server.TransferRequest(targetPath,true)

However, I now no longer have any of the custom HttpContext.Items that I added, before the transfer.

Anyone have any ideas as to how I overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344903.aspx), it preserves the querystring and Form collection, but it says nothing about context items. I'd say that you'll have to send them in other way: querystring or session.

Comment: Neither of those are really an option, due to the nature of the URL rewriting nodule that we've built.